# routine to backup ssas databases fails with: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed

Tags: sql-server, permissions, linked-server, ssas, distributed-transactions

I have developed my own stored procedure, that through a LINKED SERVER, backups the SSAS databases according to a table value parameter.

the code for the stored procedure is below.

the problem:

it works well for not so big databases (up to 4 GB lets say) but when the database is bigger (12 GB) it is giving me the error message below: (I run it from a job scheduled to run every night). I am wondering what could be missing.

error:

```
Executed as user: mycompany\SQLAgent
<Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">                  
<Object>                <DatabaseID>MYDATABASE BI LIVE</DatabaseID> </Object>               
<File>E:\SQLBackups\mydatabase BI LIVE_2014-11-04_235858.abf</File>
<AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite> </Backup>
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "MYSSASSERVER" returned message "XML for Analysis parser: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed.". [SQLSTATE 01000] 
(Message 7412)  -- Exception was caught --05 Nov 2014 00:08:58:940  
The error number:7215  Severity: 17  State: 1  Procedure: sp_backupSSAS  
Line number: 126  Error Message: Could not execute statement on remote server 'myssasserver'.   
-- End of Procedure 05 Nov 2014 00:08:58:940 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0).  The step succeeded.
```

THE PROCEDURE SP_BACKUPSSAS:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_backupSSAS]    Script Date: 05/11/2014 10:19:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--DROP PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_backupSSAS]
   @DBS  SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup READONLY


/*
=======================================================================
Script  :   PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS
Author  :   Marcelo Miorelli
Date    :   03-NOV-2014
Desc    :   
            Backup the SSAS databases that are on table @DBS
            needs the LINKED server to SSAS - in this case [SSASSERVER]
            On the first version I left that static.

Credits:  the credits for the Original idea  go to Theo Ekelmans
          http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/automatic/97696/



Usage   :           

DECLARE @DBS AS SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup 
--INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('MYCOMPANY BI LIVE','H:\SQLBackups\SSASSERVER\')
INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('Pyramid Demo 2013','\\SQLREPLON1\SQLBackups\SSASSERVER\')

EXEC sp_backupSSAS @DBS


=======================================================================
History
Date        Action      User            Desc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<Add Date>  Created     <add your name> <add description of change>

=======================================================================
*/

--======================================
-- describe primary blocks of processing
--======================================

------------------------------------------------
-- describe action of logical groups of commands
------------------------------------------------

-- describe individual actions within a command set


AS 


SET NOCOUNT ON
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED


DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- Cube name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- Backup path
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- Backup filename 
DECLARE @DT VARCHAR(20) -- Used for optional file name timestamp
Declare @XMLA nvarchar(4000) -- The SSAS command in XML format


-- Change timestamp to this format: _YYYY-MM-DD_HHMMSS
Set @DT = '_' + Replace(Replace(Convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 120), ':', ''), ' ', '_');

DECLARE @RADHE TABLE ( i int not null identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                       CATALOG_NAME  SYSNAME NOT NULL)

DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @Z INT

DECLARE  @log NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@vCrlf CHAR(2);

SELECT  @log = ''
       ,@vCrlf = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);

INSERT INTO @RADHE (CATALOG_NAME) 
SELECT CATALOG_NAME 
FROM OPENQUERY([SSASSERVER], 'SELECT [CATALOG_NAME] FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS') as a


SELECT @Z = @@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @I = 1


WHILE @I <= @Z BEGIN

  SELECT @NAME = CATALOG_NAME 
    FROM @RADHE WHERE I = @I

  --====================================================================
  -- check whether the database is contained in @DBS 
  -- get the path from @DBS where you want to backup the database
  -- if yes then backup the database, if not then skip
  --====================================================================

  SELECT @PATH = NULL

  SELECT @path = LocationName FROM @DBS WHERE DBName = @NAME 

    IF (@PATH IS NOT NULL) BEGIN 

             ---Create the XMLA string (add a DT stamp to the filename)
             Set @XMLA = N'
             <Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
                <Object>
                <DatabaseID>' + @name + '</DatabaseID>
                </Object>
                <File>' + @path + @name + @DT + '.abf</File>
                <AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite>
             </Backup>
             ';


            BEGIN TRY

                print CAST (@XMLA AS NTEXT)

                -- Execute the string across the linked server (SSAS)
                Exec (@XMLA) At [SSASSERVER]

            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH

                    SELECT
                            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage


                            SELECT @log = @log + '-- Exception was caught --' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113)  + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'The error number:' + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_NUMBER()  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Severity: '        + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_SEVERITY()  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'State: '           + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_STATE() as varchar(max)), 'No Info')  + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Procedure: '       + coalesce(cast ( coalesce(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'No Info')  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'Line number: '     + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_LINE() as varchar(max)), 'No Info')  + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Error Message: '   + cast ( coalesce(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'No Info')  as varchar(max)) + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + ' -- End of Procedure ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113) + @vCrlf  

                            PRINT CAST(@LOG AS NTEXT)

                            WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
                                    ROLLBACK

            END CATCH




    END --IF

    SELECT @I += 1

END
```

the parameter definition:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup] AS TABLE(
    [DBName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [varchar](1008) NULL
)
GO
```

example of how to call the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @DBS AS SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup 
--INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('MYCOMPANY BI LIVE','H:\SQLBackups\SSASSERVER\')
INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('Pyramid Demo 2013','\\SQLREPLON1\SQLBackups\SSASSERVER\')

EXEC sp_backupSSAS @DBS
```

When I right click the SSAS server in SSMS and look at properties this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: If you right click the SSAS server in SSMS and look at properties, what do you see under commit timeout and force commit timeout?

Comment: @JamesAnderson CommitTimeout is 0 and Force Commit Timeout is 30,000

Comment: So if you increase the force commit does it take longer for the job to fail?

Comment: @JamesAnderson from 30000 I moved it to 90000 but the job keeps failing

Comment: But did it take longer to fail?

Comment: I found out that I have a problem related to the linked server to SSAS. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82379/linked-server-from-sql-server-to-ssas-not-working-what-is-missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides what @James raised on the comments regarding the SSAS settings of commit timeout and force commit timeout,
It was the change that I did on SQL Server that make it work at the end.

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote query timeout (s)', N'6000'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

this is the same value as you can see on the picture below:
you get there by sql server server, right click properties,connections.

[image]

And also on the Analysis Server Properties, the "Commit Timeout" and "Force Commit Timeout" as you can see on the picture below.
[image]

Now I have backed up the SSAS database and restored it in a development server, and it proved fine.