# How to verify a SSAS Backup and how to perform Integrity Checks in SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, backup, powershell, data-integrity

I have a [procedure to backup SSAS Databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81928/routine-to-backup-ssas-databases-fails-with-the-xml-for-analysis-request-timed) that is working successfully.

I also [delete the SSAS backup files that are older than 2 days](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83068/run-a-powershell-script-on-a-different-server-from-inside-a-sql-server-job/83089#83089).

What I am looking forward to implement is:

1) How to verify my SSAS backups? (restore verify only)

2) How to run a DBCC CheckDB in SSAS? (database integrity)

But I have not found any substantial documentation for these.

Any suggestions?

I know about the right-click/ Validate database on Visual Studio but I would like an automated process, not manually clicking.

[image]

Comment: related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110790/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-ssas-database-and-of-its-backups/110889#110889

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a post by Darren Gosbell, a SQL Server MVP (at the time at least).  His post can be found here:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210119182507/http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2008/09/13/ssas-verifying-backups.aspx)

He points out that you cannot run this from your desktop, but you can run it on the server to do the verification.  The instructions from 2008 are:

```
Navigate to:   <Program Files>\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.SQL08\OLAP\bin 

Then type:  msmdsrv /?
```

Look at the commands available with msmdsrv and see what you want to do.  (I am away from a SSAS installation at the moment, so I cannot verify, but it should be worth checking out.)

EDIT:
**2) How to run a DBCC CheckDB in SSAS? (database integrity)**

Starting with SQL 2016 we have a [DBCC CHECKDB command for SSAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/database-consistency-checker-dbcc-for-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver16) for Dimensional as well as Tabular

> DBCC provides on-demand database validation for Multidimensional and
> Tabular databases on an Analysis Services instance. You can execute
> DBCC in an MDX or XMLA query window in SQL Server Management Studio
> (SSMS) and trace the DBCC output in either SQL Server Profiler or
> xEvent sessions in SSMS. The command takes an object definition and
> returns either an empty result set or detailed error information if
> the object is corrupted. In this article, you’ll learn how to run the
> command, interpret results, and address any problems that arise.

Comment: @Tom V - Thanks for the preview of SQL Server 2016's DBCC CHECKDB for SSAS.  (It is about time).