# How can I pass the server name as parameter for a XMLA script?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, ssas

I have a PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS - it backups SSAS databases.
**it works fine**.

I had previous problems with it, but they were sorted out here:
[routine to backup ssas databases fails with: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81928/routine-to-backup-ssas-databases-fails-with-the-xml-for-analysis-request-timed)

generally I try to have SSAS on a server of its own - let's say **server_SSAS**

therefore I use  a different server - let's say **SERVER_SQL** to backup the SSAS databases in the **server_SSAS**.

for me to run my procedure sp_backupSSAS that lives on server_SQL
I first create a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE SSAS_DBs_to_Backup AS TABLE 
( DBName sysname not null 
  ,LocationName varchar(1008)
);
GO
```

This table type is used when I call the procedure.
It tells me which database(s) to backup and the location where to put them (in the **SERVER_SSAS**)

From inside a job on SERVER_SQL:

```
DECLARE @DBS AS SSAS_DBs_to_Backup 

INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('MY Company BI LIVE','H:\SQLBackups\')

EXEC sp_backupSSAS @DBS
```

This creates a backup on my server_SSAS which is called SQLBILON1:

[image]

That is all working fine, however, I would like to pass the name of the **server_SSAS** which in this case was SQLBILON1 as a parameter, and NOT have it hard-coded inside the procedure.

how can I achieve this?

the full code of the procedure is here:

```
--SELECT @@SERVERNAME
PRINT 'THE SERVER IS ' + @@SERVERNAME
--select db_name()
PRINT 'THE DATABASE IS ' + db_NAME() 
PRINT ''





USE MASTER 
GO


--==================================================================================
--create a table type to contain the list of SSAS databases we want to backup
--==================================================================================


CREATE TYPE SSAS_DBs_to_Backup AS TABLE 
( DBName sysname not null 
  ,LocationName varchar(1008)
);
GO

BEGIN TRY
DROP PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS
   @DBS  SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup READONLY,
   @Server VARCHAR(108)


/*
=======================================================================
Script  :   PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS
Author  :   Marcelo Miorelli
Date    :   03-NOV-2014
Desc    :   
            Backup the SSAS databases that are on table @DBS
            needs the LINKED server to SSAS - in this case [SQLBILON1]
            On the first version I left that static.

Credits:  the credits for the Original idea  go to Theo Ekelmans
          http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/automatic/97696/



Usage   :           

DECLARE @DBS AS SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup 
--INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('Boden BI LIVE','H:\SQLBackups\SQLBILON1\')
INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('Pyramid Demo 2013','\\SQLREPLON1\SQLBackups\SQLBILON1\')

EXEC sp_backupSSAS @DBS


=======================================================================
History
Date        Action      User            Desc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<Add Date>  Created     <add your name> <add description of change>

=======================================================================
*/

--======================================
-- describe primary blocks of processing
--======================================

------------------------------------------------
-- describe action of logical groups of commands
------------------------------------------------

-- describe individual actions within a command set

WITH ENCRYPTION
AS 


SET NOCOUNT ON
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED


DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- Cube name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- Backup path
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- Backup filename 
DECLARE @DT VARCHAR(20) -- Used for optional file name timestamp
Declare @XMLA nvarchar(4000) -- The SSAS command in XML format


-- Change timestamp to this format: _YYYY-MM-DD_HHMMSS
Set @DT = '_' + Replace(Replace(Convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 120), ':', ''), ' ', '_');

DECLARE @RADHE TABLE ( i int not null identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                       CATALOG_NAME  SYSNAME NOT NULL)

DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @Z INT

DECLARE  @log NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@vCrlf CHAR(2);

SELECT  @log = ''
       ,@vCrlf = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);

INSERT INTO @RADHE (CATALOG_NAME) 
SELECT CATALOG_NAME 
FROM openquery([SQLBILON1], 'SELECT [CATALOG_NAME] FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS') as a


SELECT @Z = @@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @I = 1


WHILE @I <= @Z BEGIN

  SELECT @NAME = CATALOG_NAME 
    FROM @RADHE WHERE I = @I

  --====================================================================
  -- check whether the database is contained in @DBS 
  -- get the path from @DBS where you want to backup the database
  -- if yes then backup the database, if not then skip
  --====================================================================

  SELECT @PATH = NULL

  SELECT @path = LocationName FROM @DBS WHERE DBName = @NAME 

    IF (@PATH IS NOT NULL) BEGIN 

             ---Create the XMLA string (add a DT stamp to the filename)
             Set @XMLA = N'
             <Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
                <Object>
                <DatabaseID>' + @name + '</DatabaseID>
                </Object>
                <File>' + @path + @name + @DT + '.abf</File>
                <AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite>
             </Backup>
             ';


            BEGIN TRY

                --print CAST (@XMLA AS NTEXT)

                -- Execute the string across the linked server (SSAS)
                Exec (@XMLA) At [SQLBILON1]

            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH

                    SELECT
                            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage


                            SELECT @log = @log + '-- Exception was caught --' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113)  + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'The error number:' + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_NUMBER()  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Severity: '        + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_SEVERITY()  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'State: '           + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_STATE() as varchar(max)), 'No Info')  + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Procedure: '       + coalesce(cast ( coalesce(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'No Info')  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'Line number: '     + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_LINE() as varchar(max)), 'No Info')  + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Error Message: '   + cast ( coalesce(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'No Info')  as varchar(max)) + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + ' -- End of Procedure ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113) + @vCrlf  

                            PRINT CAST(@LOG AS NTEXT) + @vCrlf  

                            WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
                                    ROLLBACK

            END CATCH




    END --IF

    SELECT @I += 1

END   

GO

exec sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sp_backupSSAS'

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this procedure runs XMLA statements in a SSAS server from a SQL Server.

first we need to create the linked server to the SSAS.
this you can see on the link below:

[How can I reduce OLEDB wait type in a SSAS linked server connection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115098/how-can-i-reduce-oledb-wait-type-in-a-ssas-linked-server-connection)

After that I have done some changes on the procedure I have posted on the question.

I will share the script here, so that it is documented.

```
--SELECT @@SERVERNAME
PRINT 'THE SERVER IS ' + @@SERVERNAME
--select db_name()
PRINT 'THE DATABASE IS ' + db_NAME() 
PRINT ''


USE MASTER 
GO

BEGIN TRY
exec sp_save @TableName ='sp_backupSSAS',@permissions='Y'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
print error_message()
END CATCH
GO

--==================================================================================
--create a table type to contain the list of SSAS databases we want to backup
--==================================================================================

BEGIN TRY

IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.types where name = 'SSAS_DBs_to_Backup') 
        CREATE TYPE SSAS_DBs_to_Backup AS TABLE 
        ( DBName sysname not null 
          ,LocationName varchar(1008)
        );

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
print error_message()
END CATCH
GO


BEGIN TRY
DROP PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS
   @DBS  SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup READONLY,
   @SERVER NVARCHAR(128)


/*
=======================================================================
Script  :   PROCEDURE sp_backupSSAS
Author  :   Marcelo Miorelli
Date    :   03-NOV-2014
Desc    :   
            Backup the SSAS databases that are on table @DBS
            needs the LINKED server to SSAS - in this case [SQLBILON1]
            On the first version I left that static.

Credits:  the credits for the Original idea  go to Theo Ekelmans
          http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/automatic/97696/

Parameters: the @Server must be an already created linked server to the SSAS instance

            regarding the @DBS

            DBname is the database name
            LocationName is the path how it is seen inside the @Server.

            for instance H:\SSASBackup\ is a folder inside the server SASBIDEV01  

Usage   :           

DECLARE @DBS AS SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup 
INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('Boden BI SSAS AutoDeploy 9_01','H:\SSASBackup\')

EXEC sp_backupSSAS @DBS, 'SASBIDEV01'


=======================================================================
History
Date           Action             User                 Desc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
15-sep-2015    added feature      marcelo miorelli     added the @server as a parameter 
                                                       @server is a linked server to a SSAS server.

                                                       changed the dynamic sql to run XMLA commands on SSAS

=======================================================================
*/

--======================================
-- describe primary blocks of processing
--======================================

------------------------------------------------
-- describe action of logical groups of commands
------------------------------------------------

-- describe individual actions within a command set

WITH ENCRYPTION
AS 


SET NOCOUNT ON
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- Cube name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- Backup path
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- Backup filename 
DECLARE @DT VARCHAR(20) -- Used for optional file name timestamp
Declare @XMLA nvarchar(4000) -- The SSAS command in XML format


-- Change timestamp to this format: _YYYY-MM-DD_HHMMSS
Set @DT = '_' + Replace(Replace(Convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 120), ':', ''), ' ', '_');

DECLARE @RADHE TABLE ( i int not null identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                       CATALOG_NAME  SYSNAME NOT NULL)

DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @Z INT

DECLARE  @log NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@vCrlf CHAR(2);

SELECT  @log = ''
       ,@vCrlf = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT @SERVER = COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SERVER))),@@SERVERNAME)


IF NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT * 
                  FROM SYS.SERVERS
                  WHERE NAME = @SERVER
                    AND provider = 'MSOLAP'
                    AND is_data_access_enabled = 1
) BEGIN

           SELECT @SQL = 'The server called %s cound not be found, or does not have data access enabled.' + @vCrlf + @vCrlf +
                         'sp_backupSSAS usage:' + @vCrlf +
                         'DECLARE @DBS AS SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup ' + @vCrlf +
                         'INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES (''Pyramid Demo 2013'',''\\SQLREPLON1\SQLBackups\SQLBILON1\'') ' + @vCrlf +
                         'EXEC sp_backupSSAS @DBS, ''SASBI01''' + @vCrlf 

           RAISERROR(@SQL ,16,1,@SERVER)
           RETURN (-1)


END 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT CATALOG_NAME 
                              FROM OPENQUERY(' + quotename(@SERVER ) + ',' + '''' + 'SELECT [CATALOG_NAME] FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS' + '''' + ')'

                INSERT INTO @Radhe
                exec ( @sql)


SELECT @Z = @@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @I = 1

WHILE @I <= @Z BEGIN

  SELECT @NAME = CATALOG_NAME 
    FROM @RADHE WHERE I = @I

  --====================================================================
  -- check whether the database is contained in @DBS 
  -- get the path from @DBS where you want to backup the database
  -- if yes then backup the database, if not then skip
  --====================================================================

  SELECT @PATH = NULL

  SELECT @path = LocationName FROM @DBS WHERE DBName = @NAME 

    IF (@PATH IS NOT NULL) BEGIN 

             ---Create the XMLA string (add a DT stamp to the filename)
             Set @XMLA = N'
             <Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
                <Object>
                <DatabaseID>' + @name + '</DatabaseID>
                </Object>
                <File>' + @path + @name + @DT + '.abf</File>
                <AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite>
             </Backup>
             ';


            BEGIN TRY

                print CAST (@XMLA AS NTEXT)
                --Execute the string across the linked server (SSAS)


                SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT 
                                [n],
                                [Login_Name],
                                [Login_From],
                                [Account_Type]              
                              FROM OPENQUERY(' + quotename(@SERVER ) + ',' + '''' + @XMLA + '''' + ')'


                SELECT @SQL = 'exec (' + '''' + @XMLA + '''' + ')' + ' AT ' + quotename(@SERVER )

                print CAST (@sql AS NTEXT)

                exec (@SQL)



                --Exec (@XMLA) At [SQLBILON1]

                print 'backup is done - check the folder ' + @path

            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH

                    SELECT
                            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage


                            SELECT @log = @log + '-- Exception was caught --' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113)  + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'The error number:' + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_NUMBER()  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Severity: '        + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_SEVERITY()  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'State: '           + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_STATE() as varchar(max)), 'No Info')  + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Procedure: '       + coalesce(cast ( coalesce(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'No Info')  as varchar(max)), 'No Info') + @vCrlf  +
                                                 'Line number: '     + coalesce(cast ( ERROR_LINE() as varchar(max)), 'No Info')  + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + 'Error Message: '   + cast ( coalesce(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'No Info')  as varchar(max)) + @vCrlf  

                            SELECT @log = @log + ' -- End of Procedure ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113) + @vCrlf  

                            PRINT CAST(@LOG AS NTEXT) 

                            WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
                                    ROLLBACK

            END CATCH




    END --IF

    SELECT @I += 1

END   

GO

exec sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sp_backupSSAS'
GO
print 'The Procedure sp_backupSSAS has been created.'
GO
```

Regarding the usage:

```
DECLARE @DBS AS SSAS_DBs_to_BAckup 
INSERT INTO @DBS (DBName, LocationName) VALUES ('Boden BI SSAS AutoDeploy 9_01','H:\SSASBackup\')

EXEC sp_backupSSAS @DBS, 'SASBIDEV01'
```

> > that means that this procedure will backup the ssas database called 
> >     *Boden BI SSAS AutoDeploy 9_01* on server *SASBIDEV01* and the backup will
> >     be saved on server *SASBIDEV01*  folder *H:\SSASBackup*