# powershell problem when running on a remote server - access is denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, security, linked-server, powershell

as a follow up from this question below:

[Run a PowerShell script on a different server - from inside a SQL Server job](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83068/run-a-powershell-script-on-a-different-server-from-inside-a-sql-server-job)

there you can see that for me tu run a powershell script from inside a sql server job, I need to create a proxy.

Both the powershell script and the proxy script are on that link.

what the powershell script does is to delete old backup files on a remote server.

the question that I still have is:

for the whole thing to work on windows server 2012, I could find not other way than granting Administrator on the remote box to the Proxy account.
as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

another alternative was to 
create a powershell script that do both, backups and deletes, and create a sql server job with the following code:

[image]

Is this a powershell limitation when running on a remote server?
Are there other ways to work around it, without having to grant admin to the proxy account?

[PowerShell Basics: Managing Remote Servers & Sessions](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-remote-management,2-781.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account being local Administrator is a [requirement for using](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx) the `Enter-PSSession`:

> To connect to a remote computer, you must be a member of the Administrators group on the remote computer.

As far as workarounds, I did find [this answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/644514/94184). I would read the [article in detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/23/you-don-t-have-to-be-an-administrator-to-run-remote-powershell-commands.aspx) that the answer points to fully understand, but this is the main command to adjust permissions:

> If you decide you want to allow others, what you do is run the
>   command:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -showSecurityDescriptorUI
```

> Notice that this action could have a serious impact on your system so
>   we ask you to confirm that you really want to do this.